# Group a certain value so that the null values on next row would be on previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho

is there any workaround to remove a grouped column to be ungrouped? I want to merge the data from to rows with similar data but different grades

Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            (decode(replace(encode((rc.logo_web),'escape')::text,E'\012',''),'base64')) as school_logo,
            cs.name as student_name,
            (SELECT (concat (cs.prev_glevel_name, ' - ' , cs.prev_section))) as grade_section,
            cs.lrn,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN grss.term = 1
                    THEN ROUND(grsf.final_grade)
                    END)) as d1,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 1) >= 90 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 1) >= 85 THEN 'P'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 1) >= 80 THEN 'AP'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 1) >= 75 THEN 'D'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 1) < 75 THEN 'B'
                    END)) as l1,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN grss.term = 2
                    THEN ROUND(grsf.final_grade)
                    END)) as d2,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 2) >= 90 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 2) >= 85 THEN 'P'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 2) >= 80 THEN 'AP'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 2) >= 75 THEN 'D'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 2) < 75 THEN 'B'
                    END)) as l2,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN grss.term = 3
                    THEN ROUND(grsf.final_grade)
                    END)) as d3,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 3) >= 90 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 3) >= 85 THEN 'P'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 3) >= 80 THEN 'AP'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 3) >= 75 THEN 'D'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 3) < 75 THEN 'B'
                    END)) as l3,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN grss.term = 4
                    THEN ROUND(grsf.final_grade)
                    END)) as d4,
            (SELECT
                (CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 4) >= 90 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 4) >= 85 THEN 'P'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 4) >= 80 THEN 'AP'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 4) >= 75 THEN 'D'
                    WHEN (SELECT ROUND(grsf.final_grade) WHERE grss.term = 4) < 75 THEN 'B'
                    END)) as l4,
            csy.name as year,
            csy.principal,
            grss.term,
            ct.name as adviser,
            csu.name as subject,
            csu.sequence
        FROM config_student cs
        left join grade_record_score_summary grss on grss.grade_level_id = cs.prev_glevel and grss.section_id = cs.prev_section_id --and grss.is_deportment = False
        left join grade_record_score_final grsf on grsf.summary_id = grss.id and grsf.student_id = cs.id
        left join config_school_year csy on csy.id = grss.school_year
        left join config_period cp on cp.id = grss.term
        left join config_subject csu on csu.id = grss.subject_id
        left join grade_record_score_final_average grsfa on grsfa.student_id = cs.id
        left join config_class_list ccl on ccl.grade_level = cs.prev_glevel and ccl."section" = cs.prev_section_id
        left join config_teacher ct on ct.res_user = ccl.adviser
        left join res_company rc on rc.id = 1
        WHERE cs.id = ${student_id} and csy.id = ${year} and grsf.summary_id is not null and csu.name is not null and csu.sequence != 1000
        GROUP BY student_name, school_logo, cs.prev_glevel_name, cs.prev_section, cs.lrn, ct.name, subject, csu."sequence", grsf.final_grade, grsf.summary_id, year, grss.term, csy.principal, grsfa.final_grade
        ORDER BY csu.sequence ASC
```

and its output is like this

| school_logo | student_name | grade_section | lrn | d1 | l1 | d2 | l2 | d3 | l3 | d4 | l4 | year | principal | adviser | subject | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example | student name | grade section | lrn | 93 | A | null | null | null | null | null | null | 2020-2021 | principal | adviser | subject | sequence |
| example | student name | grade section | lrn | null | null | 80 | AP | null | null | null | null | 2020-2021 | principal | adviser | subject | sequence |

and I want to turn it like this

| school_logo | student_name | grade_section | lrn | d1 | l1 | d2 | l2 | d3 | l3 | d4 | l4 | year | principal | adviser | subject | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example | student name | grade section | lrn | 93 | A | 80 | AP | null | null | null | null | 2020-2021 | principal | adviser | subject | sequence |

where the grades from first and second row will merge into one row, any idea on how to do it? I tried to merge them by removing grss.term on GROUP BY but it sends an error. Is there any workaround on this or different approach?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use further `group by` on your existing query as follows:

```
Select school_logo,
       student_name,
       grade_section,
       lrn,
       year,
       principal,
       adviser,
       subject,
       sequence,
       Max(d1) as d1,
       Max(l1) as l1,
       Max(d2) as d2,
       Max(l2) as l2,
       .......
  From (your_query) t
Group by school_logo,
         student_name,
         grade_section,
         lrn,
         year,
         principal,
         adviser,
         subject,
         sequence
```

Comment: But my query is already on GROUP BY. Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, You can use MAX against each sub-query for l1, d1, l2, d2, ... that should give you the desired output